# Cross-application Concurrent Hashmap

Tags: java, glassfish

I am trying to share a concurrent hashmap between applications on a Glassfish (v2) server.

First question, is it at all possible?
Secondly, if it is, any suggestions?

What I am trying to achieve is a memory store (cache?) which can be quickly referenced and updated by different components on the same instance.  Implementation is a standard key/value set.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want a distributed cache.  I'd recommend looking at [Ehcache](http://ehcache.org/) and this documentation on [cache topologies](http://ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/cache-topologies).

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe you can take a look at [Hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com/) project.

Answer (score 1):

I also recommend [Hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com). It is deadly simple to use and here [some comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245487/hazelcast-vs-ehcache)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me a long time ago was placing the collection as a singleton in a library which is shared across all applications.  This way the library is loaded once and all application use that copy (and its collection)

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about 2 "applications" in the same JVM then it should certainly be possible.  If they are in the same ClassLoader then you should be able to do:

```
public class MapHolder {
    private static final ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> cache =
        new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();

    public static ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> getCacheSingleTon() {
        return cache;
    }
}
```

Then each of your modules can say something like:

```
public class Foo {
    private ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> cache =
        MapHolder.getCacheSingleTon();
}
```

This said, I'm not experienced with Glassfish.  They may already have caching modules that are available.