# In Memory Data Grids difference

Tags: caching, datagrid, datastore, in-memory-data-grid

What exactly is the difference between different IMDG's present?

Below are the following: 
Apache Ignite,
Hazelcast,
Redis, 
Infinispan,
Memcached,
XAP,
Gemfire,
Ehcache

Comment: Too broad to answer.

Comment: Can you explain in terms of use case i.e where to use specific IMDG.

Comment: I don't have much experience with all IMDGs you have listed but you can find enough information on their official pages besides if you have specific question you can ask here. There are many questions on SO as well which compares each other like https://stackoverflow.com/q/5245487/3503187